# Creating a matrix of correlated vectors

Tags: matlab, correlation

I'm trying to create 2 nxm matrices (A and B) where all columns of A and B are correlated to each other (0.6). The values in matrices A and B are drawn from separate normal distributions. I've got the following, but when I check the correlations in the output the're not 0.6. What am I doing wrong?

```
m=30
n=100    
%Two distributions
Mu1=0.0033;
stdev1=0.0208;
Mu2=0.0033;
stdev2=0.016801;
cor=0.6;
%creating a nxm matrix by calculating correlated vectors one by one
for y=1:m
W(1:n,1)=Mu1+stdev1*randn(n,1);
W(1:n,2)=Mu2+stdev2*randn(n,1);
R=[1 cor;cor 1];
L=chol(R);
W=W*L;
%Transfer to seperate matrices A and B
A(:,y)=W(:,1);
B(:,y)=W(:,2);
end
```

Comment: `corr(A(:),B(:))` results in about 0.68 for me. Is that the 'problem'?

Comment: Yes. Although the values can diverge significantly more. Last three I tried: 0.4485, 0.8335, 0.6640. Shouldn't it be at least a bit closer to the 0.6 mark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cholesky factorisation works quite well for this operation, however I have found that it gives a little too high correlation. Taking the average correlation for every row gives

corrAvg = 0.68 for n = 100 and almost the same for n = 1000

A better way to take the matrix square root in matlab is to use sqrtm.

This gives the average correlations

corrAvg = 0.61 for n = 100 and 0.60 for n = 1000.

Then of course the standard deviation is much smaller for n = 1000 and if you only use 100 values it is a bit of a problem to get a perfect 0.60 correlation for every column.

Comment: Great. Exactly what I was looking for!